# obtener la suma de un atributo django models

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

tengo un modelo `Pedido` y necesito general un resumen de todos los pedidos que se han generado en los últimos 15 días, entonces quiero generar el total de todos los pedidos y no sé como hacerlo.
de momento tengo esto:

```
pedidos = Pedido.objects.filter(fecha_pedido__range = [año + '-' + mes +'-'+ ini, anno + '-' + mes +'-' + fin])
rows=pedidos.order_by('numero_cuenta').values_list('usuario','nombre_completo','dni','banco','numero_cuenta','tipo_cuenta','precio_producto','comision','impuesto','total')
```

Esto me saca todos los pedidos pero quiero hacerle una especie de `distinct` y añadirle un campo calculado que sea la suma del campo total de todos los pedidos de cada usuario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
pedidos = Pedido.objects.filter(fecha_pedido__range = [año + '-' + mes +'-'+ ini, anno + '-' + mes +'-' + fin]).aggregate(Sum('campo a sumar'))
```

Espero te sirva